# Is it possible to conditionally ui:define in jsf?

Tags: jsf, el

I use jsf 1.2 yet
I want to do something like this:

```
<c:if test="#{'1' eq '1'}">
    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="background-color: lightblue;">
                  My special super title
              </h:panelGrid>
        </ui:define>
    </c:if>
```

this does not work - e.g. even though `'1' eq '1'` is always `true`, the `ui:define` only works when using it without `c:if`
Is there another way to achieve this?

The usecase is that I have a parent template.xhtml with something like this

```
<ui:define name="title">
  #{empty pageTitle ? 'MyAppName' : pageTitle}
</ui:define>
```

And I have two applications, App1 and App2. For App1 I have to keep the title as is, e.g.:

     #{empty pageTitle ? 'MyAppName' : pageTitle}

for App2 I have to add something fancy there, e.g. the silly panelGrid.
Is there some other semi-clean way around this?

**EDIT** i have to mention that both apps are using the same pages and templates

Comment: What condition exactly do you want to check in the fictive `<c:if>`?

Comment: @BalusC I have a bean for finding out on which app i am - e.g. #{appConfig.isApp1}

Comment: How exactly does `#{pageTitle}` play a role here? Where is it been set? By an `<ui:param>`? Why exactly is it not been set as an `<ui:define>`?

Comment: @BalusC pageTitle gets set by the developers on their final lowest level web page. I edited my answer - yes it is in the define as well.

Comment: I mean, why don't you use `<ui:define name="title">MyAppName</ui:define>` in the parent template and `<ui:define name="title">Real Page Title</ui:define>` in the template client (the lowest level web page, as you call it). You seem to be using `<ui:param name="pageTitle">Real Page Title</ui:param>` in there, which makes it really hard to abstract/decorate it further in order to solve the new requirement.

Comment: @BalusC the reason is because there is a small logic up in there. E.g. if the page is in readonly mode -> title must always be "Query Mode". If the page is in writable mode it must be `#{currentWorkFlowName}#{empty pageTitle ? '' : ' - '}#{pageTitle}` where currentWorkFlowName can be e.g. "Money Retrieval". Btw I lost the link but I upvoted it yesterday - I saw you suggested using `<ui:composition template="footer#{isSpecialFooter}.xhtml" /> ` which I could use in here. E.g. add a template for all apps in between `<ui:composition template="template_#{appConfig.appname}.xhtml" />. Backdraws?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18286/discussion-between-toskan-and-balusc)

Comment: Did you guys found out a solution for this problem? @BalusC?